# How do I show utf8 characters in pig shell aka grunt?

Tags: shell, utf-8, apache-pig

I've a file which has `UTF-8` characters like `현`. I'm taking this file as input in pig script, processing it and returning the processed string from UDF. When I use `dump` to see the output, I see `??? Processed` in grunt shell. Expected output is `현 Processed`.

How do I show UTF-8 characters on pig grunt shell?

Comment: You have failed to specify utf8 in all parts of your swine symphony.

Comment: @RickJames didn't get you. Are you asking for more clarification?

Comment: Does it work the same way when you simply DUMP the file without calling UDF?

Comment: @MikhailGolubtsov yes, it does behave in same way.

Comment: CentOS, I guess. Actually it is horton works v2.2 distribution.